# Get the mean of decimals in R

Tags: r

I import data from a CSV file like such

```
x <- c(read.csv(file="FX.csv", sep=";", header = FALSE, dec=","))
sapply(x, typeof)
```

which returns "double"

I am trying to get the mean of these numbers but I get the following

```
mean(x)
```

Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

which makes sense since the given data type is double can someone please help me to get the mean of decimals data this is what my data looks like

```
x    
$V1
     [1]  0.01  0.00  0.02  0.00  0.01  0.04 -0.02  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01 -0.01 -0.02  0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.02 -0.01  0.00
    [21]  0.01  0.01 -0.03  0.00  0.03  0.00 -0.02  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00 -0.01 -0.02  0.00  0.00 -0.02  0.03  0.00  0.01  0.00
    [41] -0.01 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.02  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.01  0.04  0.01 -0.05  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.02  0.00 -0.04 -0.01
    [61]  0.01 -0.01  0.02  0.02
```

Here is the edit as was suggested with the results

```
sapply(x, typeof)
      V1 
"double"

str(x)
'data.frame':   64 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  0.01 0 0.02 0 0.01 0.04 -0.02 0 0.01 0 ...

> sapply(x, class)
       V1 
"numeric"
```

Comment: Try: x <- read.csv(file="FX.csv", sep=";", header = FALSE, dec=",").  Adding the c in front is a array of dataframes.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `str(x)`. Also, `typeof` returns the _internal_ storage mode. In R parlance, "numeric" is essentially the same as "double". Typically, you'd do `sapply(x,class)`.

Comment: try `mean(x[[1]])` or `mean(x$V1)` ... I feel like this might very well be a dupe, since it's an easy confusion to have.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks mate did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its a `list`, your numbers are stored in the field `v1` of list `x`. 
For getting mean of numbers stored in `v1` field of list `x`, type

```
   mean(x$v1) 
   #OR
   mean(x[[1]])
```